# Mirror / rotate multi links around their starting point

Tags: qgis

I have a shp of lines; all the lines have only two vertices
I want all these traits to be "mirrored", or overturned to be clear, around their starting point.
The image explains the concept better; in red I drew the new line I would like to get by hand, while in light blue the original link.
The command must be executed on thousands of links; it is therefore not possible to execute it by line[image]
I know there are already answers on this, but nothing that works on multi links

Answer (score 1):

If each line only has 2 nodes and only want to visualize the mirrored lines you can use a Geometry generator as a layer styling in QGIS.

- Set the **Symbol layer type** to "Geometry generator" instead of the default "Simple line".
- Set the **Geometry type** to "LineString/Multilinestring"
- Use the following code as **Expression**: `make_line(start_point( $geometry), make_point(x(point_n($geometry,1))-(x(end_point($geometry)) - x(point_n($geometry,1))), y(point_n($geometry,1))-(y(end_point($geometry)) - y(point_n($geometry,1)))))`

If your layer contains Multipart geometries, you should first use "Multiparts to singleparts" in the Processing toolbox to create a new layer with only Singleparts, to use the above Expression.

**EDIT:**

If you want to save the mirrored lines, you can use the Processing Toolbox in QGIS.

- Go to the Processing Toolbox
- In the item "Vector geometry" double click on "Geometry by expression".
- Select your source layer as "Input layer"
- Select "Line" as "Output geometry type".
- In "Geometry expression" add `make_line(start_point( $geometry), make_point(x(point_n($geometry,1))-(x(end_point($geometry)) - x(point_n($geometry,1))), y(point_n($geometry,1))-(y(end_point($geometry)) - y(point_n($geometry,1)))))`
- In "Modified geometry" select the name and location of the file you wat to save the result to.
- Click on "Run in background".

Comment: Great! It works
But I see the right result only visually; How can I get the .shp file with the modified geometry?

Comment: I've added an option to save the result to a shapefile to the solution.